# I have been getting 403 forbidden error after uploading file from local to server?

Tags: wordpress

After changing file permissions it worked but after 2 days started getting the same error in `wordpress`. I am working on server I had changed the `.htaccess` file too but there is no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Delete your .htaccess file and update your permalink structure in admin,

[This Snap may be help you](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzESr.png)